# How to only show pop up on first page load

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to only display a pop up on the first page load, but in my current script it only shows the pop up if you refresh the page. The popup should display the first time you come to the page but not again.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
 if(getCookie('popup') !== ''){
        $('.popup-wrapper').css('display','block');      
    } else {
        setCookie('popup','open',1); 
    }

  $('.popup-close').click(function(){
    setCookie('popup','close',1);
      $('.popup-wrapper').css('display','none');
  });
});
});
// ]]></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using cookies?? If not you can use localStorage and write something a bit cleaner..

So for example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // if localStorage doesnt have the shownPopUp item 
   if(!localStorage.getItem('shownPopUp')){ 
      $('.popup-wrapper').css('display','block');      
   }

   $('.popup-close').click(function(){
      // set the shownPopUp item in localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('shownPopUp', true)
   $('.popup-wrapper').css('display','none');
   });
   });
```

});

No need for the getCookie function

Cookies are more used for server-side functions, where localStorage is better for client-side functions. So what will happen here is your users will never see the popup again unless they delete there localStorage

Comment: Thanks, the issue I am having with this code is that say i put in the address bar example.com then im taken to example.com and the pop up appears. Then if i click on a link from that page to an internal page then click on a link to take me back to example.com it takes me to http://www.example.com this allows the pop-up to load again. If I follow the steps again I the pop up wont appear for a 3rd time but it is seeing a difference between visiting example.com and http://www.example.com. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you store the shownPopUp Item the popup should never show up, just make sure in your applications tab in your dev tools, in the localStorage section it has saved the value properly

Answer (score 0):

Just add localStorage.setTtem after showing the popup. And don't forget to make the `.popup-wrapper` `display:none`

```
   if(!localStorage.getItem('shownPopUp')){ 
      $('.popup-wrapper').css('display','block');
      localStorage.setItem('shownPopUp', true);
   }
```

Comment: I seem to be seeing the same issue with this solution when i click on an internal link and i am then taken to www.example.com instead of example.com

Comment: Can you explain me what is the internal link ?